# Kendo Chart - How to change tooltip visibility without redrawing chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, kendo-ui

I'm using the `setOptions` method to dynamically show or hide the tooltip.  However, every time this changes the entire chart redraws.

Is there a way to use `setOptions` or another method to set the tooltip visibility without redrawing the chart?  I would accept a way to just prevent the re-draw animation.

`var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
 chart.setOptions({ tooltip: { visible: false } } );`

UPDATE:
Thanks to ezanker's answer below, I used the followed to prevent the chart from redrawing every time I updated the tooltip visibility.

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    render: onRender
)}

function onRender(e) {
    var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
    if (chart.options.transitions)
    {
        setTimeout(function () { //gives chart time to draw initially
            chart.setOptions({ transitions: false });
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

If you have a better way to do set transitions to false let me know.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off the animations

API: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-transitions

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    transitions: false
});
```

If you want the initial transition. You could turn it off in the render event so it will only animate the first time.

Comment: I've looked through the API and I'm not being able to find the render event.  What render event are you referring to?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I'll update my question.  Thank you so much, it worked!